# HBase with JMX exporter BindException

Tags: hbase, jmx, ambari, hdp

I have deployed HBase on Ambari HDP. I try to take HBase metrics using JMX exporter, so I add the next configuration in 'hbase-env':

`export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_exporter_javaagent.jar=7174:/opt/jmx_exporter/hbase/hbase.yml"`

I run HBase without problems, but when I try to access hbase shell, it throws the next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent (InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain (InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: The address is already being used
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0 (Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind (Net.java:437)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind (Net.java:429)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind (ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind (ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.bind (ServerImpl.java:133)
at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.bind (HttpServerImpl.java:54)
at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer. <init> (HTTPServer.java:145)
at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain (JavaAgent.java:49)
... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Aborted
```

I already tried to change the port of the JMX exporter, but always is throwing BindException. If I delete the line of the JMX exporter in Hbase-env, it works fine and I can access to hbase shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based in the next article: https://blog.godatadriven.com/hbase-prometheus-monitoring, I added the following to /usr/bin/hbase, so if the port is available it export there the metrics only the first time.

```
if [ `lsof -n -i:7000 | grep LISTEN | wc -l` == "0" ]; then
  export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_exporter_javaagent.jar=7000:/opt/jmx_exporter/hbase/hbase.yml"
fi
```

The problem was, that every time you tried to start services of HBase there were ports conflicts so it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The same is for me . Even though i put the the below code in /bin/hbase am still getting this error :

[root@xxx ~]# hbase shell
Checking port 7000 - port 7000 not in use - using port 7000
Usage: -javaagent:/path/to/JavaAgent.jar=[host:]: Collector already registered that provides name: jmx_exporter_build_info

for port in {7000..8010}; do

```
    if [ `lsof -n -i:$port | grep LISTEN | wc -l` == "1" ]; then
            echo "Checking port $port - port $port in use"
    else
            echo "Checking port $port - port $port not in use - using port $port"
            export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -javaagent:/hdptmp/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.0.jar=$port:/hdptmp/hbase_jmx_config.yaml"
            break
    fi
```

done

Answer (score 0):

dont write $HBASE_OPTS so that it will not be called again, that why you are getting that error. If you are pasting javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_exporter_javaagent.jar=7174:/opt/jmx_exporter/hbase/hbase.yml" in any env file then dont need to write $Hbase, if you wite them in lib folder then it should export to env file.

Take out $HBASE_OPTS it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For me following is working

```
if [ `netstat -lptn | grep ':7000' | wc -l` -eq "0" ]; then
        export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -javaagent:/user/jmx-connector/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.18.0.jar=7000:/user/jmx-connector/config.yaml"
fi
```

added to `/usr/bin/hbase`